# Has "which were" been omitted before " noted" in this text?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

Has "which were" been omitted before " noted" in this text?

- But there is no other evidence that the Persians of this period were the slaves of any such superstition as that noted by Ammianus.

The text comes from the book *The History of Sassanian "New Persian" Empire*,
by George Rawlinson.

Comment: "Superstition" is singular, so should the question be about *"which **was**"*?

Comment: This should have been migrated to English.SE or closed outright. Questions about existing literary works are off-topic here.

Answer (score 2):

Adding those words would not be wrong. If I had written the sentence, I would have added it, but I tend to be wordy. In any case, the sentence as written is correct.

Comment: You may wish to reconsider 'Adding those words would not be wrong'; @Chronocidal explains why.

Answer (score 0):

> Has "which were" been omitted before " noted" in this text?

No.

**1** But there is no other evidence that the Persians of this period were the slaves of any such ***superstition*** as ***that*** noted by Ammianus.

In this context, "**that**" is a [demonstrative] pronoun whose referent is  "**superstition**"

which gives

**2** But there is no other evidence that the Persians of this period were the slaves of any such ***superstition*** as ***that one*** noted by Ammianus.

which gives

**3** But there is no other evidence that the Persians of this period were the slaves of any such *superstition* as *that* **superstition** noted by Ammianus.

which, finally gives

**4** But there is no other evidence that the Persians of this period were the slaves of any such *superstition* as *that* *superstition* ***that was*** noted by Ammianus.